# How to get rid of overflow of css circles - "overflow: hidden" not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have made two circles using css that are half displayed on the screen so that they are semi circles. On all my other pages of the application there is no overflow because I use either overflow: hidden or overflow-x: hidden. However It does not work for this design.

Do I need to redesign and get rid of the circles or is there a fix for this?

Link to codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/ad1ecea4268).

Code also below

Notes:

- For reference this is being developed mobile first so put it in mobile view as not designed desktop or tablet yet
- Not sure why but when using dev tools with code sandbox it does'nt actually work properly in terms of how it looks on my localhost the only issue I have is the overflow-x - ignore the positioning issue with header or footer and the contents if it arises

FAQPage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import CardModal from '../Components/Modals/CardModal';
import { FAQModal } from '../Data/MenuModalData';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


export const FAQPage = () => {

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div style={{height: "100vh", overflowX: "hidden"}}>
            <Container style={{height: "100%", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", overflow: "hidden"}}>
                <TopCircle/>
                <Title>FAQS</Title>
                <QuestionBox onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    How Long Is Delivery?
                    <CardModal  {...FAQModal[0]}  open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
                </QuestionBox>
                <QuestionBox style={{marginBottom: "60%"}} onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    Are There Vegan Options?
                    <CardModal  {...FAQModal[0]}  open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
                </QuestionBox>
                <QuestionBox style={{marginBottom: "25%"}} onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    Are You On Deliveroo?
                    <CardModal  {...FAQModal[0]}  open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
                </QuestionBox>
                <QuestionBox  style={{marginBottom: "-10%"}} onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    Do You Accept PayPal?
                    <CardModal  {...FAQModal[0]}  open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
                </QuestionBox>
                <ContactBox>
                    <ContactBoxText>
                        Got Another Question?
                    </ContactBoxText>
                    <Link style={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }} to="/contact">
                        <ContactButton>
                            Get In Touch!
                        </ContactButton>
                    </Link>

                </ContactBox>
                <BottomCircle/>
            </Container>
        </div>
            
        
    )
}

const TopCircle = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 125%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(149, 225, 211, 0.4);
    top: 0%;

    @media (max-width: 360px){
        height: 185px;
    }
`
const BottomCircle = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 125%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(149, 225, 211, 0.4);
    bottom: -30%;

    @media (max-height: 600px){
        height: 150px;
    }

    @media (max-height: 640px){
        height: 175px;
    }


`

const Title = styled.span`
    position: absolute;

    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

    margin-bottom: 150%;

`
const QuestionBox = styled.button`
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    border-radius: 25px;
    /* box-shadow:  #393E46; */
    margin-bottom: 95%;


    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(149, 225, 211, 0.4);
`
const ContactBox = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    height: 125px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(149, 225, 211, 0.4);
    margin-bottom: -80%;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 75px 75px;
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 2px 1px #393E46;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

`
const ContactBoxText = styled.span`
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-style: normal;
   
    text-align: center;

    top: 20%;

`
const ContactButton = styled.button`
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 15px;
`
```

Comment: Why is your width set to 125%? You have overflow beacause of that. If you set it to 100%, you won't have that problem.

Comment: Set to 125% for the design (size of circle) - thanks for the heads up! so I cant have a circle that wide then? I thought I could do that and then use overflo-x: hidden so it was still that big just would cut it off and not display it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your issue:

1. Since you are trying to hide absolute positioned elements you need to make sure that the container of those absolute positioned elements is **relatively** positioned. By defalut, it's position is `static`. Therefore add following `css` code to your  `<div style={{height: "100vh", overflowX: "hidden", position:"relative"}}>`, then you will need to change top and bottom properties of your `TopCircle` and `BottomCircle` components.
2. Chage `width` attribute of `TopCircle` and `BottomCircle` components to take `98%`, not `125%` of parent component.